# If clause with a past tense about future for hypothetical condition

Tags: past-tense, conditionals, present-tense

Is there any case in English were a future condition is represented with past tense?

E.g. "If I saw you tomorrow, I will do ..."

In some languages, it casts more doubt for the condition to happen, i.e. says the condition is very hypothetical. In other words, it means "I know I won't see him, but if I see him, which I know I won't, then I will..."

Do we have any such thing in English?

============ **Update:** ==========

I am trying to find the equivalent grammar of something in my mother tongue. In a transliterated version, when we say:

"If he agrees on the price, I [will] give him a discount": It means this is a **rule**, i.e. agreeing on the price = receiving a discount.

But when we say:

"If he agreed on the price, I [will] give him a discount":

It strongly implies that there is a specific time frame in the future, where the if clause will become a matter of past by then = "The moment that the guys have agreed on the price and I can make an action, I will apply the rule".

In other words, this is a way to **strongly emphasise on the time of decision in the future, where all the unknown conditions have been cleared**. The context is around that specific moment.

Do we have any equivalent thing in English?

For example, is this correct (and mean what I explained)?

"We will meet the guys at 10pm tomorrow. They will inspect our car and probably give us an offer. Once they make/made (?) their decision, if they **[had] agreed (?)** on my price without haggling, I will definitely give them some discount to encourage further trade with them".

Is that correct? More importantly, does this in English also have that sort of emphasising on the time of action?

Comment: This is easily answered in any reference book. We do not answer "Which one is correct?" questions here because they are considered mindless proofreading. Please present your research, but this is an incredibly basic matter that should turn up instantaneously. Please consider taking such trivial questions to our sister site for [ell.se], but understand that they too have their research requirements.

Comment: @tchrist That's not the point. I updated the question to clarify what I mean

Comment: @Ali can you clarify whether the construction you are looking for **must** have a *will* in the *then*-part (like in the example you provided)? Or is the appearance of *will* optional, as long as the *if*-part contains a 'past tense expression a future condition?

Comment: @linguisticturn TBH My question is more like "I have seen past-tense verbs being used for conditions happening in the future. Is that correct, and if so, what does it mean?"

Comment: @Ali Just to confirm, though (because tchrist and I had a debate about it), I have two questions for you: 1. Do I understand it correctly that you are **not** insisting that, in the constructions that interest you, there should be a *will* in the *then*-part of the sentence? 2. And if 1. is correct: is [29ii] in my answer, below, an example of the kind of thing that you are interested in? If not, why not?

Comment: @linguisticturn Please see the update. I hope it clarifies further

Comment: @Ali To use your example: if it is not unlikely that they will in fact agree, the correct construction is [A] *if they agree on my price without haggling, I will definitely give them…*. If it is very possible they will **not** agree, then we use [B] *if they agreed on my price without haggling, I would definitely give them…*

Comment: @Ali It is true that [B] seems to have another possible reading: an open conditional about the past. Normally the context removes the ambiguity. If the context doesn't help, this ambiguity cannot be resolved by just modifying tenses and modality ([CGEL](https://www.amazon.com/Cambridge-Grammar-English-Language/dp/0521431468), p.754); you need to use things like adjuncts of time (*tommorow*, *yesterday*, *last week*, *next week*, etc.).

Comment: @Ali There is also a doubly remote construction, but it is rare: [C] *if they had agreed on my price tomorrow without haggling, I would have definitely given them…* Here I added a time adjunct to remove the ambiguity I mentioned above and which also exists here. But when using the doubly remote construction with future time, the meaning is counterfactual: [C] implies they will not, in fact, agree on my price.

Comment: @Ali As far as tense-aspect-mood of verbs, this is about it in English. Any other shades of meaning have to be expressed through some other means, e.g. through various adjuncts.

Comment: @linguisticturn Excellent explanation. What I meant was [B] and [C] (mostly [B]); and as you said for a complete translation I would probably need various adjuncts 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the past tense (the preterite) is used in this way in English also. When used in such a way, it is said to express **modal remoteness.**

**Discussion**

Here is an example ([CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468), p.85):

[29]  ii  *If he **took** the later plane tonight he wouldn't have to rush.*

CGEL then compares it to

[30]  ii  *If he **takes** the later plane tonight he won't have to rush.*

> The difference between [29ii] and [30ii], however, is not one of time: in both cases I'm talking about future time. They belong to two different kinds of conditional construction which we call **remote** and **open**: [30ii] presents his taking the later plane tonight as an open possibility, whereas [29ii] presents it as a more remote one. Such a difference belongs to the area of meaning called modality, so that we speak of the preterite here as expressing modal remoteness.

Comment: No, he wants an unreal past tense in the protasis to combine a *will* future in the apodosis. That is not what you have.

Comment: @tchrist Are you saying this because the OP has a *will* in the example? If so, I'm not sure that the OP meant that example to be so restrictive. All they actually *wrote* was that they want 'a future condition is represented with past tense',  just as in [29].

Comment: He asks for a *will* in the "then"  part to combine with an unreal past. That does not work, although it does combine with a real past. It is always possible that he is really asking a different question than the one he wrote; this happens a lot. :/

Comment: @tchrist I certainly agree that you can't have a preterite in the protasis and a *will* in apodosis… but I am still not sure why you are so sure that OP insists on that combination. Yes, there is a *will* in the example the OP provided, but I take that to have been *merely* an example. Again, what OP actually said in words is 'a future condition is represented with past tense', with no mention of *will*.

Comment: I confess I haven't the foggiest notion what "a future condition is presented with past tense" means. I can think of not one such instance being allowed in English. That would be using the paste-tense verb *ate* to represent a future event. How would that ever work out?

Comment: @tchrist In the comments, I asked the OP to clarify. Personally, I believe that [29] ii is exactly what the OP had in mind.

Comment: Here is a preterite in the protasis and a *will* in the apodosis: “If he left / did leave me half of his lunch, then I will have something to eat.” Isn’t it? It’s just that it's a **real past** not a hypothetical one. That’s what licenses *will* here as far as I can discern. Once you go **unreal past** you cannot do that any longer.

Comment: @tchrist This is how matters seem to me: in the *if*-part of that sentence you just wrote,  the **time referred to** is **prior** to the **time of utterance.** In contrast, in the *if*-part of [29] ii, **the time referred to** is **posterior** to **the time of utterance.** So I would say that the sentence you just wrote doesn't express a 'future condition', whereas [29] ii does. (At least that's the way I understand OP's phrase 'future condition'). In the sentence you just wrote, I would describe the *if*-part as expressing a **'past** condition' for a future event.

Comment: @tchrist Please see the update on the original post. I hope it clarifies further

Comment: @Ali Not especially, I'm afraid. We do use the English past tense to emphasize the hypothetical, but that means you will not be able to use *will*, which is the present-tense inflection of that verb; instead you need *would* in the past tense.

Answer (score 5):

## Using *will* in the apodosis
 normally requires a real protasis,
not an unreal protasis

SUMMARY: To use *will* in the "then" part, you cannot have a hypothetical in the "if" part.

---

Consider these possibilities, all grammatical but none what you say you want to do. Please pay special attention to the combinations in which the set-in-bold word ***will*** occurs: a present-tense *will* in the "then" part always means that you had reals in the "if" part, never unreals.

These are numbers 6, 12, 13, 14, and 15 below. In contrast, the unreals that take past-tense *would* in the "then" part are in 16, 17, and 19. *Will* is never hypothetical. Examples 19 and 20 are a different kind of *will* because it appears in the "if" part with a deontic sense of permission.

1. If he leaves me half of his lunch, then I have something to eat.
2. If he does leave me half of his lunch, then I do have something to eat.
3. If he left me half of his lunch, then he was not very hungry.
4. If he did leave me half of his lunch, then he was not very hungry.
5. If he  has left me half of his lunch, then he was not very hungry.
6. If he  has left me half of his lunch, then he **will** not have been very hungry.
7. If he left me half of his lunch, then I have something to eat.
8. If he did leave me half of his lunch, then I have something to eat.
9. If he left me half of his lunch, then I had something to eat.
10. If he did leave me half of his lunch, then I had something to eat.
11. If he left me half of his lunch, then I did have something to eat.
12. If he leaves me half of his lunch, then I **will** have something to eat.
13. If he does leave me half of his lunch, then I **will** have something to eat.
14. If he left me half of his lunch, then I **will** have something to eat.
15. If he did leave me half of his lunch, then I **will** have something to eat.
16. If he left me half of his lunch, then I would have something to eat.
17. If he were to leave me half of his lunch, then I would have something to eat.
18. If he were to have left me half of his lunch, then I would have had something to eat.
19. If he **will** leave me half of his lunch, then I **will** have something to eat.
20. If he **will** have left me half of his lunch, then I **will** have something to eat.

Notice where there are bold instances of **will** above.  When they are in the "then" part, you know that the "if" part cannot have been unreal, cannot have been “hypothetical”; it must have been a **real** present or a **real** past in the “if” — or in the final and rather rare cases, a deontic *will* in the "if".

That's why this is **not** grammatical:

21. ❌  If only he had left me half his lunch, I  ❌ **will** have something to eat.

So the answer is no, you cannot do what you say you want to do: you do not get to use *will* with an unreal past as you seem to desire.  You may only use *will* in the apodosis if there is a real protasis, not an unreal protasis.

If you have an unreal protasis, you have to use *would*, the past tense of *will*, in the apodosis. That’s because you have to backshift present-tense *will* into past-tense *would* there to make it line up and be unreal.

Another poster has suggested that you may not have asked what you wanted to know. If so, then please do not be surprised that I will not have attempted to answer something you will not have written. :)